# Non-informative priors for the AR(1) model

Tags: time-series, bayesian, prior

I have a question about the AR(1) model.  Expressed mathematically as:

$$ Z_{t} = \rho Z_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}, t=1,..,T$$
$$ \epsilon_{t} \sim iid \ N(0,1) $$

My question is about the "transformation group" method of creating non-informative priors, which I believe initially was suggested by Edwin Jaynes (and is discussed in Chapter 12 of his book *Probability Theory: The Logic of Science*).

One possible suggestion for a transformation group is to consider "reversing" the time series and then rescaling.  Thus my transformation group is the following:

$$\rho^{(1)} = \rho^{-1}$$
$$Z_{t}^{(1)} = \rho^{(1)}Z_{T-t+1}$$

Using the original AR distribution, you can show that this transformation basically just "shuffles" the $\epsilon_{t}$ terms, which by definition of the model are exchangeable.  So, estimating $\rho$ using $Z_{t}$ is equivalent to estimating $\rho^{(1)}$ using $Z_{t}^{(1)}$ (*i.e.*, the joint distribution of the noise is the same in both cases).  Thus the prior for $\rho^{(1)}$ must be the probability transform of the prior for $\rho$.  Or, in mathematical terms, the prior must satisfy the following functional equation:

$$f(\rho)=|{\frac{\partial \rho^{-1}}{\partial \rho}}| f(\rho^{-1})=\rho^{-2}f(\rho^{-1})$$

Unfortunately this does not describe a unique function.  In fact, any function with the following form will satisfy the above functional equation:

$$
  f(\rho) = (constant) \times \begin{bmatrix}
       \ \rho^{2b} (1-\rho^{2})^{a} & |\rho|<1 \\
       \ \rho^{-2(b+a+1)} (\rho^{2}-1)^{a} & |\rho|>1           
     \end{bmatrix}.$$

For $a > -1$ and $b>-\frac{1}{2}$ this distribution is proper, with the normalizing constant being the reciprocal of $2\beta(b+\frac{1}{2},a+1)$ where $\beta(a,b)$ is the "beta integral".  Note that this class includes the "symmetric reference prior" recommended in *Berger, J. O. and Yang, R. (1994). Noninformative priors and Bayesian testing for the AR(1) model. Econometric Theory 10 461–482.*

Usually specifying a transformation group makes the solution unique, so I am perplexed as to how this group of transformations does not produce a unique solution.  Have I done something wrong in the process of creating the transformation group?

UPDATE:Perhaps there is no transformation group which uniquely determines the prior in this case?

Comment: After a bit of maths, the class of distributions above all give $p(|\rho|<1)=\frac{1}{2}$ so that can't be used as a criterion for making the solution unique.

Comment: Clearly $\Pr(|\rho| \lt 1) = 1/2$ by symmetry: no calculations are needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This transformation group is discrete and finite: it contains exactly two elements, the identity and inverting $\rho$.  It's simply not big enough to determine a prior.  In fact, you can choose any measurable function $f$ defined on $[-1,1]$ provided (a) it is integrable and (b) $\rho^{-2}f(1/\rho)d\rho$ is integrable on $[1, \infty]$.  The latter restricts $f$ only in a neighborhood of $0$.

BTW, for this model to be practical you need to introduce a nuisance parameter $\sigma$: $\epsilon_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$.

Comment: I could also introduce a location parameter $\mu$ So that $Z_{t}$ effectively gets replaced with $\frac{X_{t}-\mu}{\sigma}$, but then the prior would just get multiplied by $\frac{1}{\sigma}$, so the example I have given doesn't make the task any easier

Comment: @probabilityislogic Yes, you're right that leaving out these parameters does not simplify the problem.

Comment: I'm thinking from the lack of articles on it, perhaps no transformation group big enough exist? this group was the only one I could think of which left the problem unchanged to someone who was "completely ignorant".  I may update my question to reflect this